# ripple effect coming without the background color

Tags: android

I am trying to implement ripple effect on my button and its working fine but the problem is the color of the button is gone , though  i have given the color in the ripple.xml file , it just removed the color and showing the effect only . Also i am only able to user line and oval effect, unable to use ring and rectangle,
please suggest .

ripple.xml is below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:color="?android:colorControlHighlight">
    <item android:id="@android:id/mask">
     <shape android:shape="rectangle">
     <solid android:color="#A3080C" />
      </shape>
    </item>
</ripple>
```